# dependency_overrides not working in FastAPI, Pytest

Tags: python, dependencies, pytest, overriding, fastapi

For my tests I want to use a test database and for that I use dependency overriding. However, my endpoints are also accessing the production database.

**My Structure Code:**

```
 src \
 . . .|auth \
 . . .| . . . |router.py\
 . . .|main.py\
tests\
 . . .|conftest.py\
 . . .|test_auth.py
```

**main.py**

```
app = FastAPI(
        title="Grid Bot Backend"
        )
routers = APIRouter(prefix="/api/v1")
routers.include_router(auth_router)
```

**auth.router.py**

```
 @router.post(
        "/register",
        summary="Create User",
        response_model=UserOut,
        dependencies=[Depends(check_user)],
    )
    async def register_user(data: UserIn, session=Depends(get_async_session)):
        data.password = get_hashed_password(data.password)
        new_user = User(**data.dict())
        session.add(new_user)
        await session.flush()
        token = create_token()
        new_token = Token(user_id=new_user.id, token=token)
        session.add(new_token)
        await session.commit()
        return UserOut(token=token, username=data.username, email=data.email)
```

**tests.conftest.py**

```
DATABASE_URL_TEST = f"postgresql+asyncpg://{TEST_DB_USER}..."
engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL_TEST)
test_async_session_maker = async_sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False)

async def override_get_async_session() -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncSession, None]:
    async with test_async_session_maker() as session:
        yield session

app.dependency_overrides[get_async_session] = override_get_async_session
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
async def ac() -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncClient, None]:
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/v1/") as ac:
        yield ac
```

**tests.test_auth.py**

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_router_register_user(ac: AsyncClient, test_db: AsyncSession):
    data: UserIn = UserIn(
            email="test@gmail.com", 
            username="test", 
            password="test1234"
            )
    body = data.dict()
    response = await ac.post("/auth/register", json=body)
    assert response.status_code == 422 or 1 == 1
```

Comment: Noone can help you without seeing your code

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally added a question without code

Comment: Whare are you importing `get_async_session` from? What does that function look like? If the function you're overriding and the function defined in the `Depends` call are different functions - have you tried checking if your `override_get_async_session` function gets called at all? Also output/add a debugging step to verify what is being returned by the `Depends` call.